# Surface Pro 3 keeps failing to boot Windows

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro-3

This device is about 15 months old. Yesterday i tried to boot the device and noticed it would only boot to the Surface UEFI screen.

What I've tried:
-Resetting the device using the press and hold volume down trick = no success
-turning off Secure Boot = no success

What has half-worked
Creating a bootable media Windows USB stick from the Microsoft website and booting to that. 
When this boots up I'm presented with the option to unlock  (bit locker) the drive or skip. If I press skip I can access start up repair, trouble shoot, device reinstall etc. However none of this works - probably because the drive is still encrypted as I pressed skip.
If I decrypt the disk using the key stored automatically on my Microsoft online account the device prompts for a reboot. If I let it reboot on the default boot order it will boot back to UEFI screen. If I boot into the USB it will start Windows normally and I can use PC as normal.

Issue:
This has half-worked because I can get into windows with a combination of the USB, bitlocker key and a reboot. Except without the USB it will just go back to the Uefi. It's not actually fixed it the issue and I can't get to any of the USB recover options (reset, troubleshoot etc) as after entering the key it will reboot to windows...

I had feared the SSD had failed and the bootloader could not see my OS disk. but the fact I can still use windows as normal shows me this is a software issue not hardware.
I can only imagine the device was doing some update or similar when the battery went flat.

Comment: Will windows restart properly, or does the problem occur from power off and during a restart?

Comment: Restarting Windows will appear to restart as normal but will boot back into Uefi screen

Comment: What happens if you hold the shift key and restart? This should take you in to the troubleshooting menu. You can try to work your way through a startup repair there. You might also try doing the shift-restart and if you can’t restart then use he USB drive to boot. Then after the USB drive restarts maybe it will hit the other troubleshooting menu instead of booting windows.

Comment: OK, will give it a shot. Should I keep Secure Boot and TPM on or off during this process?

Comment: Those settings shouldn’t be changed for any reason. Nothing you’re doing should require that. In fact changing TPM settings will affect BitLocker.